# Calculator App Change default Window Height

Tags: window

I'm quite inexperienced in Emacs and Elisp, but I've already made some good shameful things happen.

So I'm able to resize the Calculator App Window Size by setting the `calculator-mode window-resize` to a different value.

I also know that the calculator app without the `calculator-electric-mode` set to `true` the app will split the selected window below with minimum height of 2.

My question is, without changing the `calculator.el` file how do I set that minimum value to another value or how do I run a function to resize the window every time the calculator starts.

Comment: I think perhaps you want `(setq calc-window-height 20)` (or whatever value) in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)?  See also `C-h v calc-window-height`.

Comment: I couldn't tell what you were referring to by "calculator-mode window-resize" though, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I can't find that variable. I think I might have generated more confusion here. When I run the calculator app it opens on a new frame but the height is too low for my modeline so I need it to open on a bigger window. I also tried to add an hook for the creation of the buffer but no success.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're talking about `calculator.el` rather than `calc.el`.  The latter is rather more famous, and I jumped to the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply enlarge the window by using `enlarge-window` from the `calculator-mode-hook` as follows:

```lisp
(add-hook 'calculator-mode-hook (lambda () (enlarge-window 5)))
```

of course for the `enlarge-window` you can use any number you prefer.

Comment: Yes this hook works correctly. I was not aware of enlarge-window function!

Comment: Great! FYI, the enlarge-window function I found in the docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Change-Window.html).

Comment: Tiago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988206/324105 might be valuable to you, in that case.